# What is JOBOBJECT_CPU_RATE_CONTROL_INFORMATION MinRate?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm pinvoking some c++ Job object functions, and I implemented both MinRate and MaxRate. MaxRate is self explanatory, I lower it and my program slows down, but what does MinRate do?

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448384(v=vs.85).aspx) says that it reserves a certain amount of processor cycles, but the rest of my system can still use those cycles even with the number absurdly high (9990).

Does this indicate an error in my code, or is there some "soft" reservation the nuance and purpose of which escapes me?